# Testimonials with Dynamic Tenure

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, random

I'm trying to combine what will be two arrays, into one working together (not `concat()`) and I am looking for advice in regards to best practices and recommendations. The goal is to create a script (javascript only, not jQuery) that writes a random employee testimony from the list of testimonies stored in the first array, and then dynamically write how many years they've been with the company by looking at the second array, finding their hire date (year only), and subtracting that from the current year.

Here's my first array:

```
<script>
  var r_text = new Array ();
  r_text[0] = "John Smith - Customer service - Year 5! 'The thing I love the most about company x is the people, the way the company rallies around an employee in need is truly amazing and something I have never seen before.  Company x truly has a family feel and the approachability of both management and supervisors makes for a great place to work'";
  r_text[1] = "Jane Smith - Back office - Year 9! 'The pay is above average and we have benefits, like a great health plan, paid sick days, and paid holidays.  The people are friendly and we help each other.  Supervisors are there to help you, one on one, so you can do your job efficiently.' ";
  r_text[2] = "Jane Doe - Trainer - Year 7! 'I feel lucky because I can actually say I love coming to work everyday. The atmosphere here is professional - yet personal at the same time. We are a business, yes, but we are also a family.  Our dedicated, approachable leadership team is always right behind you to help you achieve your goals.  We  come together in times of need whether it be for a local cause or to help an employee in need and it really makes me proud to say I work here and have for so many years.'";
    var i = Math.floor(3*Math.random())
    document.write(r_text[i]);
</script>
```

As you can see the names and years are in the first script already. This is what I want to move away from. I want to get this script to be self sufficient and not require any aid going forward, so I want the years to update without me or anyone else going in there and modifying the strings.

Ok, now the second array is where I'm having my first problem

I have this simple function to take this year and subtract it from a set year stored in a variable to get tenure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Get tenure</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var d = new Date();
var h = 2003 //hire date
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
document.write(d.getFullYear()-h + " years");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Alrighty so I know I need to re-write this simple function to store each person's tenure in an Array. I've tried:

```
<script>
  var hireYear = new Array ();
  hireYear[0] = 2008; //John Smith
  hireYear[1] = 2004; //Jane Smith
  hireYear[2] = 2006; //Jane Doe
   var d = new Date();
   var h = hireYear[i];
     for (var i=0;i<hireYear.length;i++)
     { 
     document.write(d.getFullYear() - hireYear[i] + " Years. <br />");
     }                      
</script>
```

which prints out:

```
5 Years. 
9 Years. 
7 Years.
```

but my dilemma is how do I get these two arrays talking to each other now? I figure since the first Array is using Math.random, the second array will be the child array, so I should change `r_text[0] = "John Smith - Customer service - Year 5!` to `r_text[0] = "John Smith - Customer service - hireYear[0]` but beyond that I'm lost. I've tried searching for a similar example of two arrays working together but all I could find was `concat()` examples and that didn't seem to apply to my needs.

**Note:** I can't do this in jQuery, it has to be done in JavaScript. I know I should not be using `document.write` so if anyone has better recommendations, they are welcome.

Thanks very much in advance for any tips, suggestions, or critique offered!

Comment: Instead of `document.write`, check out `innerHTML` - `document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML`.  You can both set it and retrieve from it.  It's not ideal, but it is the most easily readable alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of keeping 2 separate arrays you can tie the year to array element itself. You can store an object in an array element with one property `text` holding the testimonial, but with `YYYY` placeholder for actual year, and second property `yearHired` holding year when the person was hired:

```
var r_text = [];
r_text[0] = {text: "John Smith - Customer service - Year YYYY! 'The thing I love the most about company x is the people, the way the company rallies around an employee in need is truly amazing and something I have never seen before.  Company x truly has a family feel and the approachability of both management and supervisors makes for a great place to work'",
             yearHired: 2008};

r_text[1] = {text: "Jane Smith - Back office - Year YYYY! 'The pay is above average and we have benefits, like a great health plan, paid sick days, and paid holidays.  The people are friendly and we help each other.  Supervisors are there to help you, one on one, so you can do your job efficiently.' ",
             yearHired: 2004}

r_text[2] = {text: "Jane Doe - Trainer - Year YYYY! 'I feel lucky because I can actually say I love coming to work everyday. The atmosphere here is professional - yet personal at the same time. We are a business, yes, but we are also a family.  Our dedicated, approachable leadership team is always right behind you to help you achieve your goals.  We  come together in times of need whether it be for a local cause or to help an employee in need and it really makes me proud to say I work here and have for so many years.'",
             yearHired: 2006}
```

This way you have to select only one element from the array, calculate year of service and replace YYYY placeholder with the result:

```
var i = Math.floor(r_text.length * Math.random());
var d = new Date();
var s = r_text[i].text.replace('YYYY', d.getFullYear() - r_text[i].yearHired);
document.write(s);
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hrz4g/2/

And you're correct, `document.write` is not the best choice to display data. A better approach is to have a placeholder, like DIV and display data in it using `innerHTML` property.

Here's an updated demo, showing this approach: http://jsfiddle.net/hrz4g/3/